# How much memory does a char *str allocate if you don't define it after declaring it?

Tags: c, memory

So if one writes

```
char *buffer;
```

in C, One would expect that one doesn't have infinite memory to put into that buffer. So how much stuff *can* I put into that string? I'm asking because I'm using the *fread()* function to read stuff from a file and am concerned about when I would run out of memory for that var. Does it expand it as it needs more memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing if you don't want your program to crash or exhibit undefined behavior. That's just a pointer, and if you don't initialize it, it points to *something*, which may or may not be in your program's memory space. If it is, you can happily overwrite something else; if it isn't, the OS will crash your program.

Comment: But say I start writing to it (aka initialize it later?). How much will I write before I can't fit anything else in, and what happens if I do reach that limit?

Comment: If you `buffer = malloc(1024)`, you get 1024 bytes (or nothing if `malloc` fails). You can `realloc` (which, nb, may move the pointer) to get more.

Comment: Re “if you don't initialize it, it points to something”: An uninitialized popinter does not necessary point to anything. It does not necessarily have a value at all and may appear to have different values at different times. An uninitialized object has an indeterminate value; it may be an unspecified value or a trap representation. In the C standard “unspecified value” has a special meaning; C 2018 3.19.3 defines it as “valid value of the relevant type where this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance,” meaning it can be different each time you use it.

Comment: Well, it points to _somewhere_ in memory, @EricPostpischil, hence "something". My wording was vague, admittedly.

Comment: @AKX: No, it does not necessarily point to *somewhere*. One, it may point to something that is not memory at all; the address might not only not be mapped but not even be valid for the computer architecture. Two, it might not have a value at all. `printf("%p %p %p\n", (void *) buffer, (void *) buffer, (void *) buffer)` is permitted by the C standard to print three different results if `buffer` is not initialized. In other words, if an object is not initialized, the model that it holds a value does not apply…

Comment: … It is permitted to behave as if the memory is not actually connected and you get random signals each time you read it. (What happens in practice is that a compiler optimizer, knowing something is uninitialized, never bothers to perform a load-from-memory to get its value, so the arguments to the sample `printf` above are never set; they just get whatever happened to be in three different registers when `printf` is called.)

Answer (score 1):

When you define `buffer` as `char *buffer;` in the body of a function, you only define an uninitialized pointer. You cannot read from it nor write through it. As a matter of fact you cannot even read its value. All of the statements below invoke undefined behavior:

```
int main() {
    char *buffer;
    char c = *buffer;  // undefined behavior: reading from an uninitialized pointer
    *buffer = '\0';    // undefined behavior: writing through an uninitialized pointer
    printf("%p\n", (void *)buffer);  // undefined behavior: reading an uninitialized variable
}
```

Before using this pointer, you must initialize it to point to an actual object, an array of `char`:

```
    char array[100];
    buffer = array;    // you can write up to 100 bytes to buffer[0] through buffer[99]

    buffer = malloc(100);  // same unless `malloc()` returned NULL
```

Comment: Reading an uninitialized variable is not inherently undefined behavior. It is in this case because the `buffer` “could have been declared `register`” (C 2018 6.3.2 2). However, if the code were `printf("%p %p\n", (void *) &buffer, (void *) buffer);`, the behavior would be incompletely specified but not undefined (unless the C implementation has trap representations for pointers and `buffer` happened to have such a representation) since `buffer` could not have been declared `register`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I was referring to the possibility the the *C implementation has trap representations for pointers and `buffer` happened to have such a representation*. In this case, merely passing `buffer` to `printf` has undefined behavior. I fail to see how `register` makes a difference as this storage class can be ignored by the compiler.

Comment: In the example I gave, printing both `&buffer` and `buffer`, passing `buffer` to `printf` does not have undefined behavior. The involvement of `register` is because the rule in the C standard explicitly states it: “If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.” (My previous citation had a mistake; it is 6.3.2.1 2, not 6.3.2 2.)